# What does [N - 1:1] mean in system Verilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have a logic declared as

```
logic [N-1:1] Ca
```

The N would be equal to 4, in this instance. I know that [N-1:0] would be a 3 bit variable, but what difference does the one in the other part of the vector mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MSB is 3 and the LSB is 1. I.e. the variable is composed of Ca[3], Ca[2] and Ca[1]: 3 bits. [N-1:0] is an N-bit variable!

Answer (score 1):

Packed arrays (vectors) are always declared with a MSB to LSB index range. You are corrected in thinking that bit 0 is usually the LSB index, but not required. It depends on how you plan to select each individual bit.